SFMC MobilePUSH SDK error setKeychainAccessibleAttribute for iOS with Objective C
Below link directs to a issue of SalesforceCloudMarketing Error you get and its solution is also given in trailing messages,
iOS MarketingCloudSDK -v 8.0.13 and SFMCSDK -v1.08 - App Crash
This can be set in iOS if you are using swift, i want to do the same in objective c.
How can this be achieved?
